# How to sum up each element in array list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Having a bit of writing out the code.

For example, if I have an array of:

```
a = ([0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3])
```

if I want to add first element of each item,

as in to return a list of 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0, 0 + 1 + 0, 0 + 0 ...

I wrote the code:

```
def test(lst):
  sum = 0
  test_lst = [] 
  i = 0
  while i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, len(lst)):
      sum += lst[j][i]
      test_lst.append(sum)
      i += 1 
 return test_lst
```

I get index size error.
How can I go about this?

Comment: `len(a)`. Where does `a` come from?

Comment: @MorganThrapp Seems like that's the tuple of lists.

Comment: why increasing `i` and why the while loop??? F and a ???

Comment: @AndrewL. Right, but the name `a` doesn't exist in the context of the function.

Comment: oh, len(a) as in length of list a at the top?

Comment: `ls` vs `lst` !! please fix the code it's really bad.

Comment: You're not adding the first element of each item, you're adding all the elements.

Comment: `len(lst)` is the length of the whole list, not the length of an individual item in the list.

Comment: `sum(i[0] for i in a)` adds the first items...but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum(zip(*a)[0])
```

`zip` is a function that takes any number of n-length sequences and returns n tuples (among other things).  The first of these tuples has the elements that came first in the tuples passed to `zip`.  `sum` adds them together.

EDIT:

In Python 3, the above doesn't work.  Use:

```
sum(next(zip(*a)))
```

instead.  For all such sums,

```
map(sum, zip(*a))
```

Comment: Love this answer. Building on it, how about `[sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]`. Returns the entire list of results as requested by OP.

Comment: I'm jealous of your response! Way better than mine!

Comment: @THeeren `map(sum, zip(*a))`

Comment: Ah. Nice. I should get used to using map.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ([0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3])
```

Try using list comprehensions:

```
sum([item[0] for item in a])
```

The line above takes the first element of each list in the tuple, then puts it into a temporary list. We then call sum on that temporary list, which yields the answer.

Comment: But what if he need to keep `a` as a tuple?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @leaf  ! Let me make some edits.